# Stream tablet to computer with switcher to stream to internet

Tags: android, streaming, youtube

I am trying to design a cheap system that allows me to have 3 video inputs, allows me to mix them and stream it live to YouTube.

Currently I am thinking that I can stream from basic amazon/android tablets to a central computer running OBS. I could mix and apply effects and then stream from OBS to YouTube.

My main questions are what software to use to import a stream into OBS and what software to use to create the stream on the tablet.

Overall I would prefer a solution that already exists, but would be able to create an app with existing libraries to do some of the work.